# os.rename() creates new file instead of renaming file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, windows-10

So, I'm using tkinter with python 3 and windows 10 (64 bit). I have a save function, that saves what's written in several entry boxes as a .txt file. The user can then open the .txt files from the application, and all of the data will go back to its original position. As part of my program, a label displays the file name of the currently open file. The user can edit the filename from within the window.

When the user saves, I want to change the filename of the file to what the user has written in the window. This works for the most part. However, if the user has written anything in the entry box, and changes the filename within my application, when they save it doesn't just change the actual filename.

Instead, it just creates a new file with the name of the new filename. It also spits the error:

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Python stuff/Other apps/Veteris/Scripts/test.txt' -> 'test2.txt'
```

I'm using the os.rename() function. Also, when the user opens a file, I can't get the filename to display. Any help on that would also be appreciated. Here is my code:

```py
def _open():
    global file_dir

    file_dir = tkfd.askopenfilename(title = "Open...", defaultextension = 
                   '.txt', filetypes = (('Text files', '*.txt'), ('Excel 
                    Workbook', '*.xlsx')))

    if file_dir.endswith('.txt'):
        with open(file_dir, 'r') as input_file:
                    # saves stuff

    elif file_dir.endswith('.xlsx'):
           # saves stuff

    new_file_name = os.path.basename(file_dir.name).strip('.txt.xlsx')

    file_title.config(text = new_file_name)

def save_as():
    global filepath
    global file_dir
    global file_name
    global save_status


    file_dir = tkfd.asksaveasfilename(initialfile = file_name, initialdir 
                 = filepath, title = "Save as", defaultextension = '.txt', 
                 filetypes = [('Text files', '*.txt')]) # Sets file_dir to the 
                  directory the user creates (in save as dialog)

    try:
        with open(file_dir, 'w') as output_file:
                # saves the stuff


        time_saved_label.config(text = "Saved")
        save_status = True

    except:
        print("'Save as' cancelled")

def save():
    global file_dir
    global file_name
    global save_status

    notepad_save = notepad.get('1.0', END).strip('\n')

    eyes_save = eyes_entry.get().strip('\n') + '\n'
    if file_dir is None:
        return save_as()

    else: 
        with open(file_dir, 'w') as output_file:


            output_file.write(notepad_save)

        new_file_name = file_name + '.txt'
        os.rename(file_dir, new_file_name)
```

Like I said, the code should change the name of the file and that's it (along with updating the contents).

Instead, it just creates a copy with the most recent changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the line with [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) should be:

```py
os.rename(file_dir + file_name, file_dir + new_file_name)
```

Comment: This just brings up the error: ```FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Python stuff/Other apps/Veteris/Scripts/test.txttest23' -> 'test23.txt'```

Comment: What is the real name of the text file to rename?

Comment: It varies. The user creates and names multiple files

Comment: You maybe have to give a full path to the destination of `os.rename` instead of just a file name.

Comment: I just did that. Now, every time the user saves the file after using save as, the file disappears from the directory the user saved it in, and appears in the directory where the code is. I'm stuck!

Comment: I edit my answer in order to solve your second matter.